# Want to get session values when client sends new request

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I want to get server's session value when client creates a new request.

But, server returns nil always.

I don't know what is the problem in this case.

---

### Client

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var (
    store       *sessions.CookieStore = sessions.NewCookieStore(securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(64))
    session     *sessions.Session
    SessionName = "client"
)

func main() {
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   60 * 15,
        Secure:   false,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", cIndex)
    router.HandleFunc("/test", cTest)
    http.ListenAndServe(":7000", router)
}

func cIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, SessionName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("cIndex Session Error : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    session.Values["foo"] = "bar"
    session.Save(r, w)
    w.Header().Set("Location", "http://localhost:8080?foo=bar")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)

}

func cTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8080/test", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("cTest Request Error : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth("sample_id", "sample_secret")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    c := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{},
    }
    resp, err := c.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("cTest Response Error : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("cTest Body Error : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    log.Println(string(body))
}
```

---

### Server

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var (
    store       *sessions.CookieStore = sessions.NewCookieStore(securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(64))
    session     *sessions.Session
    SessionName = "server"
)

func main() {
    store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   60 * 15,
        Secure:   false,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", sIndex)
    router.HandleFunc("/test", sTest)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}

func sIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    v := r.FormValue("foo")
    session, err := store.Get(r, SessionName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("sIndex Session Error : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    session.Values["foo"] = v
    session.Save(r, w)
    w.Header().Set("Location", "http://localhost:7000/test")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusFound)
}

func sTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, SessionName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("sTest Session Error : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    v, ok := session.Values["foo"].(string)
    if !ok {
        log.Printf("foo = %v\n", v)
    }
    data := struct {
        Foo string
    }{
        v, // I expected v is bar,but v was nil.
    }

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("sTest JSON Error : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(bytes)
}
```

---

### Details

1. Client sends request to server with query `foo=bar`.
2. Server receives the request and parsing.
3. Server saves query parameter in session.(I used `gorilla/session`)
4. Client makes `*http.Client` and send new Request to server.
5. Server receives request, and loads value in session, and set the value at response.
6. Client receives value `bar`

---

In 5, I expected that server can load the value `bar` from session, but session value was nil.

Comment: @Flimzy Oh, when I wrote the code, there are no errors. I thought `session, _ := store.Get(r, SessionName)` is correct, so I'm not wrote that. Sorry.

Comment: There are no errors occured when I wrote that codes.
So I omitted `err` statement when I wrote this question.
I thought `req, err := http.NewRequest(<method>, <url>, <body>)` statement creates new request, and server creates new session for request.
I wrote wrong title for this question. Sorry.
I meant `I want to use client.Do() method using existing request `.
My English skill is so terrible, so I couldn't describe that I wanted.
I really appreciate you, Flimzy. Thank you.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately, we don't know that... so it's always best to use your _actual_ code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some codes and it moves.
Is it correct way?

Client

```
func cTest(w http.ResponseWrite, r *http.Request) {
    serverURL := "http://localhost:8080/test"
    r.Method = http.MethodGet
    r.Host = serverURL  // server
    v, err := url.Parse(serverURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("url parsing error occurred : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    c := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{}}
    resp, err := c.Transport.RoundTrip(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("client roundtrip error occurred : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("response body reading error occurred : ", err.Error())
        return
    }
    w.Write(body)
}
```